# Как JavaScript запрос выполнить в браузере из GoogleScript ввиду ошибки 403?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, http-status-code-403

Задача:
Передать запрос с определёнными параметрами в АПИ сайта - Получить ответ - Вывести этот ответ в Гугл таблицу.

Проблема:
Сервер выдаёт 403 ошибку, так как запрос выполняется на серверах Google, IP которых заблокированы.

Решение, что вижу я:
Из Google Scripts выполнять скрипт локально. Ведь в консоли браузера скрипт работает (чтобы обойти выполнение со стороны серверов Google).

Очень прошу помочь решить эту задачу, так как 5-й день я над ней бьюсь и не могу решить.
Рабочий код JavaScript, который легко можно проверить в консоли, оставлю снизу.
Код из GS не выкладываю, так как он не работает.

Возможно Вы знаете решение? Буду очень благодарен, так как я новичок.

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer 5cd4ac65-f71b-3eaa-93af-78610a7aa320");
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

var raw = JSON.stringify([
  "1111111111111"
]);

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw 
};

fetch("https://www.ukrposhta.ua/status-tracking/0.0.1/statuses/last", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
```

Вот так я переписал запрос на GS, но он не работает. Документация указывает, что contentType должен быть в headers.

```
function pleaseWork() {

  var myHeaders = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer 5cd4ac65-f71b-3eaa-93af-78610a7aa320',
    'contentType': 'application/json'
  }
  var raw = ["1111111111111"]
  
  var requestOptions = {
    'method': 'POST',    
    'headers': myHeaders,
    'payload': JSON.stringify(raw)
  };
  result = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.ukrposhta.ua/status-tracking/0.0.1/statuses/last", requestOptions)
  Logger.log(result)
}
```

Comment: Есть сомнения. Может быть не в IP дело, а в заголовке запроса или токене?

Comment: Я новичок, могу ошибаться. Но как бы я не менял это Рабочий запрос в консоли браузера ,я никогда не получаю ошибку 403.        Также, как бы я не менял запрос в AppsScript, у меня ошибка 403 или редиректит на страницу их системы антиспама. Я искренне не понимаю, как решить эту проблему.

Comment: К слову о заголовках. Есть аналог функции Headers() в AppsScript?

Comment: @contributorpw, подскажите, пожалуйста. Может вы знаете как получить параметр "Content-lenght"? По определению, это размер в байтах тела запроса. Беда только, я в GAS нигде не могу найти как это сделать.

Comment: Напишите мне contributor.pw/contacts